# Linux Centos Sendmail only sending to 20 recipients

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, sendmail

When sending emails from my centos server the 20th email address in the list is being cutoff and then not including any email addresses after that one. The 20th email address has some of the recipients name and then @vps.hostname.com

Is there a config somewhere that sets max number of email TO addresses?

Thanks

Comment: Is this `postfix` or `sendmail`? For Sendmail `sendmail`, what does `grep MaxRecipientsPerMessage /etc/mail/*.cf` show?

Comment: Sorry, sendmail. The output to that command is:            /etc/mail/sendmail.cf:#O MaxRecipientsPerMessage=0
/etc/mail/submit.cf:#O MaxRecipientsPerMessage=0

Comment: Hmm, what is doing the cut-off? Is it a local process, or something remote?